# How to change this pass by reference into pointer as function parameter

Tags: pointers

wanting to ask how to change this pass by reference into pass by pointer, cause some of my school works need pass by pointer and i doesn't really understand how to modified this code using pass by pointer

```
void convert(string &s){
    for (int i =0; i<s.length(); i++){
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
}
}

int main(){

string name;
cout<<"Enter your name"<<endl;
getline(cin,name);
convert(name);
cout<<name<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are some minor errors in the code.

1. Inlcude necessary headers.
2. Use std:: namespace prefix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void convert(std::string &s){
    for (int i =0; i < s.length(); i++){
        s[i] = std::toupper(s[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    convert(name);
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using pointer version?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#define SIZE 100

void convert(char *s, size_t size){
    for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
        s[i] = std::toupper(s[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    char name[SIZE];
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::fgets(name, SIZE, stdin);
    convert(name, strlen(name));
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Another version using pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void convert(std::string *s){
    for (int i =0; i < s -> length(); i++){
        (*s)[i] = std::toupper((*s)[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    std::string *name = new std::string();
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, *name);
    convert(name);
    std::cout << *name << std::endl;

    delete name;
    return 0;
}
```